# I need more storage in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Hey guys I am just trying out Ubuntu,I have some questions (does almost everything in terminal)

1-How do I get more space on Ubuntu?

2.How do I merge the 11GB leftover partition on the left of the Ubuntu 12.4 `ext4` main partition?... I have done everything else by myself,I just don't know how to expand partition so I can download more stuff to my main Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can boot your System from LiveCD/USB-Stick, then install Gparted from Ubuntu Software Center, you can use Gparted while running the liveCD image.  With Gparted you can change the size of your ubuntu partition or move free space from other partitions to your Ubuntu partition to get more free hard disk space for your ubuntu installation. 
(dont forget to make backup before doing so)